# Scrapy with multiple url in list object

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm a junior in python.I have some question about spider.
I have catch some URL and i put in my list object, then i would like to using the URL to do Scrapy again , is that possible dynamic changing the URL and keep doing Scrapy. Or someone can give me a idea about "Scrapy", thanks a lot .

```
 'def parse(self,response):

    sel=Selector(response)
    sites=sel.xpath('//tr/td/span[@class="artist-lists"]')
    items = []

    for site in sites:
        item=Website()
        title=site.xpath('a/text()').extract()
        link=site.xpath('a/@href').extract()
        desc=site.xpath('text()').extract()

        item['title']=title[0].encode('big5')
        item['link']= link[0]
        self.get_userLink(item['link'])
        item['desc']=desc
    #   items.append(item)
    #return items



def get_userLink(self,link):

    #start_urls=[link]

    self.parse(link)
    sel=Selector(link)
    sites=sel.xpath('//table/tr/td/b')
    print sites
    #for site in sites:
        #print site.xpath('a/@href').extract() + "\n" 
        #print site.xpath('a/text()').extract()+ "\n"`
```

Comment: I recommend going through this Scrapy tutorial first: http://hopefulramble.blogspot.com.br/2014/08/web-scraping-with-scrapy-first-steps_30.html That will give you enough understanding to be able to do what you want.

Comment: Hi elias, Thanks for your recommend, i will going through this tutorial .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `yield request` that is parse the url to call other function.

```
def parse(self, response):

    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    url=  sel.xpath('//..../@href').extract()


    if url:
```

## It checks whether the url is correct or not.

```
    yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_sub)

def parse_sub(self, response):

    ** Some Scrape operation here **
```

Comment: Thanks the tutorial, i will try and now i using different way to do scrapy like i saved all the url in a txt file and rescrapy again. Thanks a lot have a nice day :)